# How to add One Day to SYSTEM_DATE in WSO2 EI Property Mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am getting the server date using the below property mediator

```
<property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyy-MM-dd')" name="date" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

I get the value as '2021-09-07'. Now I would like to get the previous day and next day from the SYSTEM_DATE (E.g., 2021-09-06 and 2021-09-08). How can I achieve this in WSO2 ESB?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to achieve that, so you need use script mediator. For example something like below.

```
<script language="js">
   var date = new Date();                 
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
   mc.setProperty('NextDay',date.toISOString().slice(0, 10))
   date.setDate(date.getDate() - 2);
   mc.setProperty('PreviousDay',date.toISOString().slice(0, 10))      
</script>
```

Keep in mind that the above solution does **not** take into account your timezone offset.